# Material-UI Theme : How to manage order or priority the .MuiXXX classes are applied?

Tags: styles, material-ui, themes

**[EDIT April 19th]**

I have created a [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-cache-9zfjb) to show the problem, of course, that doesn't occur in sandbox. 
**The only difference between this code and mine is that I have duplicated the code of the Button component in the SANDBOX example, whereas in my App the Button component is imported from a library (that belongs to the same yarn workspace as the app)**. The library is built with webpack and babel, excluding React and Material-UI

```
externals: {
    react: "react",
    "react-dom": "react-dom",
    "react-router": "react-router",
    "react-router-dom": "react-router-dom",
    "@material-ui/core": "@material-ui/core",
    "@material-ui/icons": "@material-ui/icons",
    "@material-ui/lab": "@material-ui/lab",
    "@material-ui/styles": "@material-ui/styles",
    formik: "formik",
},
```

Inspecting the components in the Browser shows the difference when styling, between sandbox and my app :

on both sides, the class are applied to the component the same way:

**in sandbox**
[image]

**in my app**
[image]

but **on sandBox**, the `MuiButtonBase-root background-color` is overridden by the `MuiButton-root background-color`
[image]

whereas it is the opposite in my app. The `MuiButton-root backGroundColor` seems to be overriden bu the `MuiButtonBase-root background-color`
[image]

**However,** if I create a component `RecreatedButton` in the App by just importing the `Button component of my UI Library`, and re-exported it without changing anything (just passing a specific props the component is requested), then the styling is applied correctly, as in the sandbox example.

this is kind of weird to me...

Why such a behavior ?

**just importing and rexporting as is the component**

```
   import {
        Button as LibraryButton,
        EButtonTypes,
        IButtonProps,
    } from "@mylibrairy/reactcomponentscommon";  <---- importing the button
    import React from "react";

const RecreatedButton: React.FC<IButtonProps> = (
    props: IButtonProps
): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <LibraryButton type={EButtonTypes.BUTTON}>
            {props.children}
        </LibraryButton>
    );
};

export { RecreatedButton };
```

**Using both in app.ts. One got the theme, the other not**

```
    import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import {
        Button as LibraryButton,
        EButtonTypes,
        IButtonProps,
    } from "@mylibrairy/reactcomponentscommon"
    import React from "react";
    import AppBar from "../../UIComponents/AppBar";
    import { RecreatedButton } from "../../UIComponents/Button";
    import { MUITheme } from "./../../Theming/defaultTheme";

    export const MainApp: React.FC = (): JSX.Element => {
        return (
            <ThemeProvider theme={MUITheme}>
                <>
                    <AppBar />
                    <LibraryButton type={EButtonTypes.BUTTON}> I'm the library component, directly used as is, and background color is NOT CORRECT ></LibraryButton>
                    <RecreatedButton>
                        I'm recreated button, just rexporting the library component, and the backgroundcolor is correct !?!?{" "}
                    </RecreatedButton>
                </>
            </ThemeProvider>
        );
    };
```

Comment: Can you add a working example? https://codesandbox.io is a good place to start.

Comment: @Dekel, have created a sandback which doesn't reproduce the issue, but shows the differences in stryling on Browser dev tools, between the sandbox and my app.

Comment: Can you try and spend a bit more time to create a demo that shows exactly the issue? Otherwise it will be a bit more harder to understand what exactly you are after.

Comment: well I have added again some information, but as long as my librairy is in a yarn workspace, I don't know how to reproduce the same context in codesandbox, which I'm not familiar with at all

Answer (score 4):

finally I found one solution (not sure that it fixes the root cause as I still do not understand where it comes from).

I Guess it may helps some people here that are facing a similar issue with global theming in Material-Ui.

It turned out that I had to change the way to build my react/material-Ui components library `@mylibrairy/reactcomponentscommon`.

1- Make sure that in the library, all imports where such as `import { Button} from "@material-ui/core"` and not for example `import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button"`

2- Remove the usage of `file-loader plugin` in the `.babelrc` to make sure it doesn't change the way to import material-ui components

3- Push `@material-ui/core` and `@material-ui/icons` as a `dev and peer dependencies` in the `package.json` of the library.

4- Rebuilt the library using webpack and babel to compile typescript tsx to js.

All issues of priority seems to disappear (have done a lot of tests and checked in the chrome dev tools). In the example above, the `.MuiButton-root` class is well applied after the  `.MuiButtonBase-root` one, thus overriding as expected the `backgroundColor`.

Would admit that I'm a little bit confused why this fixed the issue...

Rgds

Comment: Just doing Step 1 and then rebuilding with webpack resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

For me, i just had to import "makeStyles" and "createStyles" from "@material-ui/core" not from "@material-ui/core/styles". i just did this and it fixed the issue but took me a lot of time to figure this out.

so import them like this:

```
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
```

not like this:

```
import { makeStyles, createStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try overriding default globals for `MuiButtonBase`

[image]

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  props: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiButtonBase: {
      // The default props to change
      root:{
        backgroundColor: 'red' 
      }
    },
  },
});

function DefaultProps() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button>Change default props</Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Working sandbox here - https://codesandbox.io/s/override-button-base-7qwd5

Comment: this is what I will do at the end, but this is kind of duplicating the job, as all styling elements that are common to MuiButtonBase and MuiButton ...are already defined.

Comment: Not sure how this will duplicate the job.If you have a global theme defined for your application , its a single place change without requiring any upadate of your components codebase.